# cms page load a phtml not displaying

Tags: blocks, magento-1, cms, phtml

i have a cms page the url = "home, and the content have the following home contains the following code:

```
{{block type="irecommend/view" name="product_list_home3" category_id_new="533" template="my/irecommend/home_view.phtml" }}
```

but the phtml not displaying, anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to

System->permission->blocks

and click on addnewblock  add your block `irecommend/view` and save and clear your cache and try again